# Read Parquet Files from HDFS cluster

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi

looking for an advice on how to read parquet file from hdfs cluster using Apache Nifi. In the cluster, there are multiple files present under single directory, want to read all in one flow. Does Nifi provide an inbuilt component to read the files in HDFS directory (parquet in this case)?

example- 3 files present in directory-

hdfs://app/data/customer/file1.parquet

hdfs://app/data/customer/file2.parquet

hdfs://app/data/customer/file3.parquet

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement is to read the files from HDFS, you can use the HDFS processors available in the `nifi-hadoop-bundle`. You can use either of the two approaches:

- A combination of `ListHDFS` and `FetchHDFS`
- `GetHDFS`

The difference between the two approaches is `GetHDFS` will keep listing the contents of the directories that is configured for each run, so it will produce duplicates. The former approach, however, keeps track of the state so only new additions and/or modifications are returned in each subsequent runs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **FetchParquet** processor in combination with **ListHDFS/GetHDFS..etc** processors.

This processor added starting from NiFi-1.2 version and Jira [NiFi-3724](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3724) addressing this improvement.

- ***ListHD*FS** //stores the state and runs incrementally.
- ***GetHDFS*** //doesn't stores the state get's all the files from the configured directory **(Keep source file property to True incase you don't want to delete the source file)**.
- You can use some other ways(using UpdateAttribute..etc) to add **fully qualified filename as attribute** to the flowfile then feed the connection to FetchParquet processor then processor fetches those parquet files.

Based on the **RecordWriter** specified `FetchParquet` Processor `reads parquet files` and write them in the format specified in **RecordWriter**.

**Flow:**

```
ListHDFS/GetHDFS -> FetchParquet -> other processors
```